# Isotope properties plotting tool?

Tags: nuclear-physics, software, isotopes

I'm looking for something that will generate scatter plots comparing different properties of isotopes. Ideally I'd like some web page that lets me select axis and click go but a CSV file with lost of properties would work.

Comment: This seems like the kind of question to ask on the [webapps SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). But I guess it could go here too... (admittedly there probably aren't that many people on webapps.SE who are familiar with nuclear physics)

Comment: @David: First, I also thought that this is off-topic but now (after exchanging few comments with Frédéric and looking at some other software questions) I tend to think that it is fine (especially considering the *software* tag). Also, there is the reason you stated: this probably wouldn't get answered anywhere else.

Comment: I chose to post it here because primarily the question is about the data set and secondarily about the tooling.

Answer (score 4):

[Chart of Nuclides](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/)?

Or like [this](http://atom.kaeri.re.kr/)

Answer (score 1):

[Exploring the Table of Isotopes](http://ie.lbl.gov/education/isotopes.htm) is my go-to site.

There are a few others out there, but when I moved from my last computer those were some of the bookmarks I *didn't* bring, 'cause I never used them...

You haven't specified what you want in your CVS file. I think this site only offers transition energies and branching fractions by radiation type.

For searching a whole database of transistions for lines of [energy range]$\times$[A or Z range]$\times$[halflife range] use [The Lund/LBNL Nuclear Data Search](http://nucleardata.nuclear.lu.se/NuclearData/toi/). Very useful if you are thinking of building a novel calibration source or some thing like that. This site also has stopping powers and other good stuff (go up a level from the link...). Another go-to resource.

Comment: What I was hoping to do was plot N vs λ. The spesific problem I'm interested in is what's with the bite mark in this chart at N~=130?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Isotopes_and_half-life.svg